# Java insert into table with auto increment field

Tags: java, sql, insert, key

How can I insert into a table with primary key autoincrement?
I want to use prepared statements and I keep getting this error 0<1...
I tried with statement and it works :S

```
public void insertDobavitelj (String dobavitelj,String naslov, String telefon) {

    String query = "INSERT INTO dobavitelj(ime,naslov,telefon) VALUES ('"+dobavitelj+"','"+naslov+"','"+telefon+"')";

    try {

          Class.forName(driver);
          conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

          Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
          stmt.executeUpdate(query);

          /*stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
         // stmt.setInt(1, 0);
          stmt.setString(0, dobavitelj);
          stmt.setString(1, naslov);
          stmt.setString(2, telefon);


          if (stmt.executeUpdate() == 1) {
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Uspesno ste dodali novega dobavitelja");
          }
         */


    }catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,"Class not found - insert dobavitelj" );
    }catch (SQLException exception) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "SQL Exception - insert dobavitelj");
           exception.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I've tried with:

```
"INSERT INTO dobavitelj(ime,naslov,telefon) VALUES ('?'.'?','?')"
"INSERT INTO dobavitelj(idDobavitelja,ime,naslov,telefon) VALUES (?.'?'.'?','?')"
```

Thanx good people :)

Comment: Which field is `auto incrememet`? And don't include that field in your `INSERT`.

Comment: I would recommend using the [`INSERT INTO ...SET`](http://milov.nl/2836) syntax - it's much clearer.

Comment: @BoristheSpider `INSERT INTO .. SET` is not standard, but MySQL specific.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `stmt.setString(0, dobavitelj);` with a zero as index, the statement indexes start at 1.

Also change your query syntax to this: `INSERT INTO dobavitelj(ime,naslov,telefon) VALUES ('?'.'?','?')`

Answer (score 0):

you can create a random number variable which you will insert in the auto increment column in mysql. multiply the random number by 1000 to get 999 values or 10000 to have 9999 values limit;
`int randomnumber = (int) math.random() * 1000` 
`statement.setInt(1, randomnumber)`